# Would past simple be a better choice?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Look at this sentence extract from Emir Kusturica's Wikipedia article:

> Despite the aforementioned conflict of religion, Kusturica refused to see himself as either a Bosniak or Serb. Instead, he **had continued** to insist that he was simply a Yugoslav.[39]

Does **had continued** indicate that this feeling of being Yugoslav began before the refusal but did it continue after it?

Don't you think the use of **had continued** past perfect is not very judicious because if you say continue it is because it began before. So we can understand that he always felt Yugoslavian and it began a long time before the refusal and maybe after the refusal even if Yugoslavia did not exist at the refusal time. So would not be past simple a better choice?

Comment: I agree that past simple would probably be a better choice.

Comment: After the time referred to in the quotation, did anything related to this happen. Such as he changed his mind and considered himself of a different nationality?

Comment: No he did not change his mind that is why I think past simple is better

Comment: Which is the 'better' choice is a matter of style and opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the text talks of a particular moment in history.  Imagine yourself transported to the time exactly at that moment.  Imagine that it is *now*.  Can you *now* say that Kusturica *now* **has** (for some time, unknown from what day exactly) **continued** (meaning repeatedly done so) calling himself "Yugoslav"?  Saying "Kusturica **continues** ..." gives it a different meaning, doesn't it?

Let's come back to our time, and if you agree that the choice of Present Perfect ("has continued") was OK for the day we magically visited, the use of Past Perfect is justified *over* Past Indefinite.

Comment: I think that continues and has continued for me have the same meaning if something continues that means it began before  so what are the difference in the meaning ? In both cases  we don't know when it began  and in both cases it still continues

Comment: The difference that I feel popping up in my mind (although not so strongly perhaps as to be convincing beyond any doubt) is that Present Perfect suggests, and puts the emphasis on the fact, that the action began some time in the past, whereas Present Indefinite does no such thing.